# Small thing about input using while loop

Tags: c++, input, while-loop

I hope you guys all are having a great day!

I have a quick question about using the while loop for competitive programming (we do not know the size of the input, so we have to read until the end of file or 0 value)
For this particular program, the program end with 2 values of 0 as  "0 0", and the code I saw used this:

```
while (cin >> r >> n, r || n) { 
     // code
}
```

1. My question is about the >>> , r || n <<<< part:

   - Is the while loop as the same meaning as

     ```
     while ( (cin >> r >> n) ||  (r || n) )
     ```
   - can I have some preferences to read more about the multi conditions for the while loop.

Please regard my dump question  :( Tks you all for reading this post!

Comment: How did you get from the comma operator (google that) to the `||` operator?

Comment: RTFM http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator

Comment: It is not the same meaning as || it means basically, do the left side first, then evaluate the right side and treat that expression as the value of the whole expression (see my answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically.... comma has the lowest precedence and is left-associative.

Given A , B

1. A is evaluated
2. The result of A is ignored
3. B is evaluated
4. The result of B is returned as the result.

Further Reading : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19198977/3153883

So in your case, cin loads r and n.   The return value from that operation is ignored.  r or n happens and is the result of the whole while expression.    So, a 0 0 will cause the while loop to terminate.